# Performing one hot encoding on dataframe with multiple groups

Tags: python, dataframe, one-hot-encoding

I am new to learning machine learning on datasets in `python` and am trying to perform one hot encoding on the below dataframe (only shown a snippet)

| id | country | device |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | sg | samsung |
| 100 | ch | galaxy s |
| 200 | ab | pocophone |
| 200 | ee | iphone 1 |
| 200 | my | iphone 2 |

I would like the results to be something like this

| id | sg | ch | ab | ee | my |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 200 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Would appreciate any advice and help, thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.crosstab`:

```
>>> pd.crosstab(df['id'], df['country'])[df['country']
country  sg  ch  ab  ee  my
id
100       1   1   0   0   0
200       0   0   1   1   1
```